# Is it possible to create overlays in beamer inside pgfplots graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, pgfplots

When working with pgf-tikz, I can create overlays in beamer presentations with

```
\path<overlay specification> ...
```

However, I could not get this to work in pgfplots graphics. It would be nice if something like

```
\addplot<2-> {...};
```

worked as expected, but it does not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 41):

Well, it seems that

```
\only<overlay specification>{\addplot { ... };}
```

works fine, so problem solved. I had tried with the commands \visible and uncover but it did not work.

Comment: `\draw`, `\path`, and `\node` are overlay-specification-aware, but `\addplot` comes from another package built on top of pgf and isn't.  `\only` works because it either includes or throws away its argument, whereas `\uncover` will try to set it in invisible ink, which it's not set up to do within a tikzpicture.  The only drawback of `\only` over `\uncover` is you might need to manually correct the bounding box.

Comment: Six years later, I googled this issue and stumbled on my own comment.  Wish I could vote it up!

Answer (score 6):

*This answer is adapted from [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269558/168128) by @gonzalo-medina.*

You can use the `visible on=<overlay specification>` style provided by the overlay-beamer-styles library in the [aobs-tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) package. The advantage over using `\only` is that the plot takes up space all the time but it is made invisible on the slides where it should not appear. As a result, the axis limits and dimensions of the plot will stay the same on all slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x};
            \addplot+[visible on=<2->] {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Slides showing a plot where the lines are added one by one.]