# TikZ+beamer, referencing node outside current picture, inside overprint environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

In `beamer`, when I try to reference a node outside the current picture but inside an `overprint`-environment, like this,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{overprint}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
 \node<1->[draw] (xxx) at (0,0) {Spam};
 \node<2->[draw] (yyy) at (1, 1) {Eggs};
\end{tikzpicture}
Some text, tra la la.
\tikz<2>[remember picture] \draw[overlay,->] (xxx.north) -- (yyy.south);
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and compiling with `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)`, using `beamer 2011/09/12 development version 3.12`, `tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`, I receive the following error message:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named yyy is known.
```

My questions:

- Is it possible to refer to a node inside an `overprint`-environment?
- If yes, how?
- If no, is this a fundamental limitation, or a limitation to the current implementation?
- Why is this?

Related but different questions:

- [How to make beamer overlays with Tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node)
- [Is it possible to create overlays in beamer inside pgfplots graphics?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/is-it-possible-to-create-overlays-in-beamer-inside-pgfplots-graphics)

Comment: The following seems to compile but you need a little work to fix the position of the graphics. Remove the `overprint` environment and replace it with: `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
 \node<1->[draw] (xxx) at (0,0) {Spam};
 \node<2->[draw] (yyy) at (1, 1) {Eggs};
\draw<2>[overlay,->] (xxx.north) -- (yyy.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
Some text, tra la la.`

Comment: In my actual example (removed for the MWE) I have a different image (outside the tikzpicture environment) in one of the slides. But Andrew's solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `\tikz` command itself is not overlay-aware.  (I think that it would be quite difficult to make it so.)  So the `\tikz` stuff is getting executed on every slide, but the `yyy` node doesn't exist until the second slide so it doesn't know what to do with it.  If you shift the `<2>` to the `\draw` instead then it works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{overprint}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
 \node<1->[draw] (xxx) at (0,0) {Spam};
 \node<2->[draw] (yyy) at (1, 1) {Eggs};
\end{tikzpicture}
Some text, tra la la.
\tikz[remember picture] \draw<2>[overlay,->] (xxx.north) -- (yyy.south);
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```