# Retain coordinate value in tikz foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to retain a computed coordinate value from one step of a tikz foreach loop to the next.  In the code below, I would like the increment in the y-value to depend on the previous y-value, which I am denoting \lasty.  Is there a way to retain this value?  Thanks for the help.  The example below errors out including the `- \lasty`; the example should work otherwise.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\newcommand{\Emmett}[6]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
\draw[#4] (0,0)
\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx] in {1,...,749}
{   -- ++(#2,{rand*#3 + #2*(#6-\lasty)/(#1-\x)})
}
node[right] {#5};
}
\scalebox{0.5}{   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,-5) grid (15,5);
\Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{red}{first one}{2.0}
\Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{green}{second one}{-1.0}
\Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{blue}{third one}{-2.0}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\pgfmathsetseed{1337}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure about understanding your problem but may be this answer to [How to fix the trajectory of Brownian motions which generated by the “rand” function with tikz in beamer frames](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60370/1952) could help you. It proposes to save all random generated values into data files and use them later without having to compute (or remeber) them again.

Comment: Yes, I think that might work.  I'm trying to plot several Brownian bridges.

Comment: Is it `\lastx` or `\lasty`? If all are `\lasty` try `[remember=\x as \lasty (initially 0)]` or define `\lasty` before the loop as zero

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution which remembers previous `y` values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ae@path{}
\newcommand{\Emmett}[6]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
  \def\ae@last@y{0}
  \def\ae@initial@portion{\draw[#4] (0,0)}
  \xdef\ae@path{\expandonce\ae@initial@portion}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,749}
  {   
    \pgfmathparse{rand*#3 + #2*(#6-\ae@last@y)/(#1-\x)}
    \xdef\ae@last@y{\pgfmathresult}
    \xdef\ae@path{\expandonce\ae@path -- ++(#2,\expandonce\ae@last@y)}
  }
  \ae@path node[right] {#5};
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.5}{   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,-5) grid (15,5);
\Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{red}{first one}{2.0}
\Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{green}{second one}{-1.0}
\Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{blue}{third one}{-2.0}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%\pgfmathsetseed{1337}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### \typeout for debugging

Here for debugging purposes, you can see that they y's are being properly updated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ae@path{}
\newcommand{\Emmett}[6]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
  \def\ae@last@y{0}
  \def\ae@initial@portion{\draw[#4] (0,0)}
  \xdef\ae@path{\expandonce\ae@initial@portion}
  \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)]in {1,...,749}
  {   
    \typeout{==>--------------------------------------------------}%%
    \typeout{==>(x=\x) ==> (old y=\ae@last@y)}%%
    \pgfmathparse{rand*#3 + #2*(#6-\ae@last@y)/(#1-\x)}
    \xdef\ae@last@y{\pgfmathresult}
    \typeout{==>(x=\x) ==> (new y=\ae@last@y)}%%
    \xdef\ae@path{\expandonce\ae@path -- ++(#2,\expandonce\ae@last@y)}
  }
  \ae@path node[right] {#5};
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \scalebox{0.5}{   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[help lines] (0,-5) grid (15,5);
      \Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{red}{first one}{2.0}
      \Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{green}{second one}{-1.0}
      \Emmett{750}{0.02}{0.2}{blue}{third one}{-2.0}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    %\pgfmathsetseed{1337}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do want the previous y coordinate rather than the previous x coordinate, as it looks like you are trying to do in the second part of your answer.  The second code provided still does not retain the y-value.  For example, consider starting the line at (0,5) and incrementing by -#2*\ae@last@y (`\pgfmathparse{-#2*\ae@last@y))}`).  This plots a flat line rather than a declining one.

Comment: @kevin It's remembering things correctly.  I've added some more lines to type out the values so you can see how they change.

Comment: @kevin, `\xdef<cmd>{<definition>}` fully expands the definition for `<cmd>` before the assignment takes place.  It also does so globally.  `\def` would be completely ineffective, and `\edef` would not do so globally.