# Plotting a Brownian motion with dashed line indicating the values

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a plot that look similar to the one below in LaTeX (through either TikZ or something else). I have already found a method to plot the Brownian path. However, I do not know how to add the dashed lines shown in the picture below. These lines are made when the Brownian path hits a particular value and the labels will be letters rather than numbers. Thank you!

[image: An Example]

Actually, the method to plot the Brownian path I found is here:
[How to draw Brownian motions in tikz/pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59926/how-to-draw-brownian-motions-in-tikz-pgf)

I don't need to add upper bound or lower bound as in the answers in that link. But, I do need to add some dashed lines for some particular values.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have for the plot without the dashed lines?

Comment: Please add the code for plotting the Brownian path. The way how to draw the dashed lines depends on the way how you draw the graph.

Comment: May be you can save the brownian path inside a pgfplotstable (like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60370/1952) and read the values from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt using [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`, follow the links for more details.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

% set a seed, so it is repeatable (it will work fine if you 
% delete this, but you will get a different path...)
randomseed := 1288.27463;

numeric a, u, v, wt, N, hi, lo;
% parameters
a = 0;
N = 100;
lo = -hi = infinity;
wt = 2/5; % weight - larger = more random

% scales
u = 1mm; % scale
v = 1cm;

% make the brownian path, keeping track of the hi and lo points
% you could use uniformdeviate or calculate a more complicated
% distribution here instead of "normaldeviate"
path A;
A = (origin for t=1 upto N: 
        hide( 
            if a>hi: hi := a; fi if a<lo: lo := a; fi 
            a := a + wt * normaldeviate; 
        )
        -- (t,a) 
     endfor) xscaled u yscaled v;

% draw in the axes nicely
drawoptions(withcolor 1/2 white);
draw ((0,lo)--(0,hi)) scaled v;
for i=ceiling(lo) upto floor(hi) : 
    draw (left--right) scaled 2 shifted (0,i*v);
    label.lft("$" & decimal i & "$", (0,i*v)); 
endfor
draw (origin--right) scaled (N*u);

% draw the markers at the desired points along the brownian motion path
drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor 2/3 blue);

z0 = point 44 of A; 
draw (x0,-16) -- z0 -- (-16,y0); 
label.bot("$T_0$", (x0,-16));
label.lft("$M_0$", (-16,y0));

z1 = point 81 of A; 
draw (x1,-16) -- z1 -- (-16,y1); 
label.bot("$T_1$", (x1,-16));
label.lft("$M_1$", (-16,y1));

% etc...

% finally draw the path on top of everything else
drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 red);
draw A;

drawoptions();
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```