# How to plot noise signal added to a received signal

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce this figure using Latex, but the I can't find a command that can replicate the nice signal
[image]

Comment: First, produce some Gaussian white noise, then apply a digital filter to band limit it, finally add it to your noise free signal.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60370/1952