# Beamer: uncover, overlay, pause not working

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am trying to do a Beamer presentation with some `uncover` features, but it turns out that `uncover`, `overlay` and `pause` are not working. Just the `only` command works.

If I compile the following example, just the `only` command will produce different output slides, the other commands produce 3 slides with exactly the same content: all the text, not uncovered at all.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{onslide}
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<+->{\begin{block}{block 1}
   block 1
\end{block}}
\onslide<+->{\begin{block}{block 2}
   block 2 
\end{block}}
\onslide<+->{\begin{block}{block 3}
   block 3
 \end{block}}
 \end{overprint}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{only}
 \only<1>{\begin{block}{block 1}
   block 1
 \end{block}}
 \only<2>{\begin{block}{block 2}
   block 2
 \end{block}}
 \only<3>{\begin{block}{block 3}
   block 3
 \end{block}}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{pause}
 \begin{block}{block 1}
   block 1
 \end{block}\pause
 \begin{block}{block 2}
   block 2
 \end{block}\pause
 \begin{block}{block 3}
   block 3
 \end{block}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{uncover}

  \uncover<+->{\begin{block}{block 1}
   block 1
 \end{block}}
 \uncover<+->{\begin{block}{block 2}
   block 2
 \end{block}}
 \uncover<+->{\begin{block}{block 3}
   block 3
 \end{block}}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong? Can it be my Beamer version?

Comment: Can you post the LaTeX output that you get when compiling this file? Perhaps it provides some hints.

Comment: How can I upload the log file? Anyway I don't see anything useful

Comment: You can post a log in the same way as you posted code -- this will add a second text box. The log will contain useful information, such as package versions, the type of latex compiler used, etc.

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up the effects realised by the different commands you tried. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a brief description of the different commands you tried to use:

**Only**

This is used either `\only<x>{}`, `\only<x-z>{}` or `\only<x,y>{}` and will output what is between `{}` only on the slide(s) (resp.) x, x to z or x and y. It does not allocate some sort of space for what is between the `{}` on the other slide so that

```
 \begin{frame}{only}

 \only<1>{\begin{block}{block 1}
   block 1
 \end{block}}
 \only<2>{\begin{block}{block 2}
   block 2
 \end{block}}
 \only<3>{\begin{block}{block 3}
   block 3
 \end{block}}
 \end{frame}
```

produces:

[image: Output Only]

**Pause**

`\pause` is a command used to add a *pause* to the frame you are building. It means that everything that is placed before the pause will be displayed on the first slide corresponding to the frame and everything that follows (but before the next `\pause` command if you use more than one on the same frame) will be displayed on the next slide corresponding to the frame.

It can be seen as if you were saying to Beamer, here I want you to stop the slide and wait for me to press a key before you output the following on the next slide *without removing what is before*.

This feature is very useful when unrevealing items from a list if you need to add some comment about the items and you don't want the audience to see the next items while you are dealing with the previous one.

Here is your code:

```
 \begin{frame}{pause}

 \begin{block}{block 1}
   block 1
 \end{block}
\pause
 \begin{block}{block 2}
   block 2
 \end{block}
\pause
 \begin{block}{block 3}
   block 3
 \end{block}
 \end{frame}
```

and its output:

[image: Output pause]

**Uncover**

This command can be used either like `\uncover<x->{}`, `\uncover<x-z>{}` or `\uncover<x>{}` and will output what is between the `{}` from the (resp.) x to the end slides, the x to z slides, only on the x slide.

On the illustration below you can see that even if the part between the `{}` is hidden, some space is allocated to it and will not be used to display something else (to compare with the only command)

Here is an example

```
 \begin{frame}{uncover}

  \uncover<1->{\begin{block}{block 1}
   block 1
 \end{block}}
 \uncover<2>{\begin{block}{block 2}
   block 2
 \end{block}}
 \uncover<3>{\begin{block}{block 3}
   block 3
 \end{block}}
```

and its output:

[image: Output uncover]

**General comments**

It exists a lot of other ways to reveal, overwrite, overlay and so on. parts of slides using Beamer. This is just simple explanations using the most common ones. One should add to these list the `\item<x>` and other derivatives from this one used to reveal sequentially the items of a list (more or less the same goal as pause but with more control if you to remove something which has been displayed).

I hope this helps for your purpose and I think you are looking for the `\only` command according to the description you made in your question. If not please clarify it.

Comment: Thx for the comprehensive explanation. Note that `\uncover` will try to set the content in invisible ink which is not supported for some commands such as `\addplot`. In these cases, only `\only` will work (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/is-it-possible-to-create-overlays-in-beamer-inside-pgfplots-graphics#comment10586_6634).