# Simple Presentation Question

Tags: beamer

I have a simple question for `beamer` programming. I've been looking around and was quite surprised not to have found a quick answer for a seemingly simple thing, so I am posting it here.

I have a list and would like to uncover the sentences of a single item from the enumeration one by one (basically, it shows resolutions of multiple choice question; but I would like the resolution of each item to be shown little by little).

I would be grateful for any help. My failed attempts used `only`, `uncover`, and `pause`, but couldn't do the trick with those.

Comment: Does this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139130/31058) help you for your purpose?

Comment: Not quite, it creates blocks, but that is not my purpose. I just want a sentence to be revealed little by little (possibliy for making a video of my screen as well).

Comment: Also, I would like the sentence to appear once and thats it. I don't the sentence to appear very dim at first and then uncovering it...

Answer (score 10):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Here are many sentences to present this item. \uncover<2->{This is the second one. \uncover<3->{And here comes a third one.}}
\uncover<4->{\item Bar}
\uncover<5->{\item Foo. \uncover<6->{Bar. \uncover<7->{Baz.}}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Outputs]

**EDIT** I did not like the typesetting of my answer (too many uncover) so here is an alternative for the same output (I added `setbeamercovered{transparent=0}` on the request of the OP). Here only the `\pause` command is used.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Here are many sentences to present this item.
\pause This is the second one.
\pause And here comes a third one.
\item \pause Bar 
\item \pause Foo.
\pause Bar.
\pause Baz.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am still having some trouble because the items still appear very dim in the background before being uncovered, so for some reason I can't replicate your example...

Comment: @MJS Try to set `\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}` in your preamble.

Comment: @LudovicC. You can use `\item<...>` instead of `\uncover<...>{\item ...}`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I agree if you want to reveal all the content of the item but what if you want to show only some part of this item?

Comment: @LudovicC. Try it (third item): `\item<5-> Foo. \uncover<6->{Bar. \uncover<7->{Baz.}}`

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes sure for this part, I thought you were speaking of all the uncovers command. I am currently trying to improve the method to get it lighter to typeset. Edit in progress.