# How can I automate this item overlay (in beamer)?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, overlays

For a presentation, I would like to reveal several items in a list in succession. Right now, the code is as follows; the corresponding (and desired) output is shown at the bottom of my post.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{itemize}
  \item stay
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<2-> one
      \item<3-> two
      \item<4-> three
    \end{itemize}
  \item stay 2
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<5-> and four
        % \item<> Ooops, forgot something
      \item<6-> and five
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

How can I automate (counters?) the revealing of the items such that there be no need to increase the numbers in `<...>` by hand. If I need to include one more `\item` somewhere at the beginning, increasing every subsequent `<...>` is tedious. I'm thinking about something like a new '\itemnext item I forgot'...

[image]

Comment: Does this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141159/31058) help you (using the `\pause` command) ?

Comment: you are looking for the `+-` operator, that allows for incremental overlay specifications, check section 9.6.4 of the manual (p. 89).

Comment: Wow, thx to all of you. The last one might be the one I searched for. Nevertheless, the other comments are interesting as well. Others might have a look into the documentation ;-) and I forgot about the \pause command that helps here, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of all your `\item` overlay specifications and simply pass `<+(1)->` as optional argument to the two inner `itemize` environments: `\begin{itemise}[<+(1)->]`. The `1` acts as an offset here; it delays the appearance of the first item by one slide. See subsubsection 9.6.4 in the [beamer manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.dante.de%2Ftex-archive%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Fbeamer%2Fdoc%2Fbeameruserguide.pdf&ei=94GkUrG0FIGI7Aa86YGYAw&usg=AFQjCNHO0Uc46Wh26Pkhq-B8eAADl8rcgw&sig2=QOY4VZrCjs2Rzkp7VddHqw&bvm=bv.57752919,d.ZGU) for more details.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{itemize}
  \item stay
    \begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
      \item one
      \item two
      \item three
    \end{itemize}
  \item stay 2
    \begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
      \item and four
        % \item<> Ooops, forgot something
      \item and five
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]