# Make curves appear one by one in one plot in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, overlays

I want to put one figure with multiple curves in my `beamer` presentation, but I want to put a pause between the curves. It means that the curves appear in the plot one by one. The `\pause` option does not work. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot table {error1 };
\pause

\addplot table {error3};
\pause

\addplot table {error5};
\pause

\end{axis}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: This is probably not so relevant, because this is an old question that has answers already, but it seems to me that it is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6632/168128.

Answer (score 22):

Another option is using the `visible on` style:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
  }
  
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[visible on=<1->] coordinates {(0,0) (5,3)};
\addplot+[visible on=<2->] coordinates {(0,-2) (5,-3)};
\addplot+[visible on=<3->] coordinates {(0,2) (5,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

Note that if you want to show the same graph on multiple slides seperated by comma, you must write the argument in curly brackets: `{<1,3>}`

Comment: Is it possible to have a variation of this style which also hides the legend entry until it is visible?

Comment: What happens if you add legends to each curve?

Comment: Note that the styles `invisible`, `visible on`, and `alt` are now in their own TikZ library `overlay-beamer-styles`.

Answer (score 13):

Using `\only` seems to work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {rnd};
\only<2->{
\addplot {rnd};}
\only<3>{
\addplot {rnd};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem with this: rather than just being invisible, the plot will not actually be drawn in earlier frames, which can cause problems with the sizing of the picture.