# showing pgfplots one by one in beamer doesn't work

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, overlays, tikz-external

I'm trying to create a plot that has many curves, and so I would like to use the `only` feature of beamer to make each curve appear one by one. This is the MWE for the figure without trying anything yet:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, shapes.geometric, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./figures/tikz/]


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[legend style={fill=none, at={(0,1.)}, anchor=north west, draw=none}]

        \addplot + [thick, mark=none] table[] {
               1                2.00
               3               25.49
                7              100.67
         };
        \addplot + [thick, dashed, mark=none] table[] {
                1                2.74
                3               12.74
                7               33.43
            };
        \addplot + [thick, mark=none] table[] {
               1               11.75
               3               46.66
               7              424.49
            };
        \legend{ curve 1 \\  curve 2 \\  curve 3 \\}        
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which creates
[image]

I need `external` because the actual presentation has tons of curves like this.
Now it would seem that making each curve appear would be as easy as enclosing each curve with `only<1->`, as I found according to the last answer [found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269548/make-curves-appear-one-by-one-in-one-plot-in-a-beamer-presentation), but it's not the case. It seems that `only` does not play nice with `external`, so I tried adding the `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` before and after the frame:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, shapes.geometric, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./figures/tikz/]


\tikzexternaldisable

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[legend style={fill=none, at={(0,1.)}, anchor=north west, draw=none}]

\only<1->{% 
        \addplot + [thick, mark=none] table[] {
               1                2.00
               3               25.49
                7              100.67
         };
}%       
\only<2>{%  
        \addplot + [thick, dashed, mark=none] table[] {
                1                2.74
                3               12.74
                7               33.43
            };
}%          
\only<3>{%
        \addplot + [thick, mark=none] table[] {
               1               11.75
               3               46.66
               7              424.49
            };
}%

        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\tikzexternalenable
\end{document}
```

I even removed the legend, but still this doesn't work and gives me `Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '" 1 2.00 3 25.49 7 100.67 "'`

Then I decided to try the actual answer [in the same post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269548/make-curves-appear-one-by-one-in-one-plot-in-a-beamer-presentation), using `visible on`. This didn't play nice with external but this time it *kind of worked* when I disable external:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, shapes.geometric, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./figures/tikz/]


\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },  
}

\tikzexternaldisable


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[legend style={fill=none, at={(0,1.)}, anchor=north west, draw=none}]

        \addplot + [thick, mark=none, visible on=<1->] table[] {
               1                2.00
               3               25.49
                7              100.67
         };

        \addplot + [thick, dashed, mark=none, visible on=<2->] table[] {
                1                2.74
                3               12.74
                7               33.43
            };

        \addplot + [thick, mark=none, visible on=<3->] table[] {
               1               11.75
               3               46.66
               7              424.49
            };

        \legend{ curve 1 \\  curve 2 \\  curve 3 \\}        
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\tikzexternalenable
\end{document}
```

But now the legends are all messed up:
[image]

I would expect that each legend appeared with its corresponding curve.
At this stage I give up as I can't figure out how to do something that seems so simple.

**UPDATE**
I partially solved the legend issue using `\addlegendentry[visible on=<1->]`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, fleqn]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, calc, spy, pgfplots.polar, shapes.geometric, external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./figures/tikz/]


\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },  
}

\tikzexternaldisable


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[legend style={fill=none, at={(0,1.)}, anchor=north west, draw=none}]

        \addplot + [thick, mark=none, visible on=<1->] table[] {
               1                2.00
               3               25.49
                7              100.67
         };
        \addlegendentry[visible on=<1->]{curve 1}

        \addplot + [thick, dashed, mark=none, visible on=<2>] table[] {
                1                2.74
                3               12.74
                7               33.43
            };
        \addlegendentry[visible on=<2>]{curve 2}

        \addplot + [thick, mark=none, visible on=<3>] table[] {
               1               11.75
               3               46.66
               7              424.49
            };
        \addlegendentry[visible on=<3>]{curve 3}

        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\tikzexternalenable


\end{document}
```

However, if I hide the second plot now the 3rd legend is not in the right place:

[image]

Comment: @aaagon

when you define the legend you could use:


 \legend{ \only<1->{curve 1} \\ 

               \only<2->{curve 2} \\ 

 \only<3->{curve 3} \\};

Answer (score 2):

@aaagon in a better formatting:

when you define the legend you could use:

> \legend{ \only<1->{curve 1} \\
>     \only<2->{curve 2} \\
>     \only<3->{curve 3} \\ };

The use of \only{} command unsure that curve and label curve appear at the same time.

Comment: @aaagon: thanks a lot, i've to learn formatting the text ...