# pgfplots - beamer reveals not working with "set layers"

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, pause

I am creating a `pgfplot` in `beamer` where visual elements are revealed step-by-step. In particular, I have added extra tick marks which appear in a later frame, using the `visible on` style described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269558).

I also have TikZ shapes which intersect with the axis, and I would like these to be displayed underneath the axis. I have tried using the `set layers` option of `pgfplots`, but this seems to ruin the reveal of the aforementioned tick marks - they just appear on the first frame, rather than a later frame. How can I ensure that both:

- the extra tick marks don't appear on the first frame; and
- shapes drawn inside the `axis` environment are placed underneath the axis?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,xtick={0,1},
    extra x ticks={0.5},extra x tick style={visible on=<2->,grid=none},
    extra x tick labels={to appear later},
    xmin=-0.05,xmax=1.05,ymin=0,
    axis line style=semithick,
%   set layers=axis on top   % Uncommenting this ruins the reveal
]
    \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=300,visible on=<2->,color=blue,line width=1pt]{0.3-0.1*x} node(endofplot)[anchor=west]{$f$};
    \draw[fill=blue!50!white,opacity=0.95] (axis cs:0.3,-0.05) rectangle (axis cs:0.6,0.1) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot `\pgfplotsset{set layers}`

Comment: @AndréC: that doesn't seem to fix anything...

Comment: This makes the axes appear at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but I think this is what you need:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    % set layers=true,
    axis on top=true,
    clip=false,
    xtick={0,1},
    extra x ticks={0.5},
    extra x tick style={visible on=<2>},
    extra x tick labels={to appear later},
    xmin=-0.05,
    xmax=1.05,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.3,
    axis line style=semithick,
]
\only<1->{\draw[fill=blue!50!white,opacity=0.95] (axis cs:0.3,-0.05) rectangle (axis cs:0.6,0.1) {};}
\only<2->{\addplot[domain=0:1,samples=300,visible on=<2->,color=blue,line width=1pt]{0.3-0.1*x} node(endofplot)[anchor=west]{$f$};}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: pgf plot with reveal]

Comment: Quick question. Isn't only and visible on redundant?

Comment: @JeT: Why don't you try it out and let us know?